# Two Equal Signs in One Line?

Tags: c

Could someone please explain what this does and how it is legal C code?  I found this line in this code: http://code.google.com/p/compression-code/downloads/list, which is a C implementation of the Vitter algorithm for [Adaptive Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Huffman_coding)

```
ArcChar = ArcBit = 0;
```

From the function:

```
void arc_put1 (unsigned bit)
{
    ArcChar <<= 1;

    if( bit )
        ArcChar |= 1;

    if( ++ArcBit < 8 )
        return;

    putc (ArcChar, Out);
    ArcChar = ArcBit = 0;
}
```

ArcChar is an `int` and ArcBit is an `unsigned char`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The value of the expression `(a = b)` is the value of `b`, so you can chain them this way. They are also right-associative, so it all works out.

Essentially

```
ArcChar = ArcBit = 0;
```

is (approximately<sup>1</sup>) the same as

```
ArcBit = 0;
ArcChar = 0;
```

since the value of the first assigment is the assigned value, thus `0`.

Regarding the types, even though `ArcBit` is an `unsigned char` the result of the assignment will get widened to `int`.

---

<sup>1</sup>   It's not *exactly* the same, though, as R.. points out in a comment below.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the data-type issue.

Comment: It's not quite the same as the two-statement version, which has a sequence point between the two assignments. This can make a difference if the two lvalues are `*ptr1` and `*ptr2` and they happen to point to the same place (in which the one-statement version would have UB) or if they're both `volatile` and you care about the order the assignments happen.

Comment: Ah, damn. And now I can't delete :-/

Comment: @R.. could you please elaborate more on the case they are both pointers? I dont get how this would matter if `*ptr1 = *ptr2 = 0;`...and what do you mean by `UB`?

Comment: @Joey I know what it is (and read it again to be sure) and still it doesn't make sense to me. I think pointer aliasing will be a problem if the values being written were different, so optimization reordering could make the final value unpredictable, but since both pointers get the same value on this case, I can't see how this would make any difference.

Comment: (`UB` stands for Undefined Behavior I get it now)

Answer (score 11):

```
ArcChar = ArcBit = 0;
```

The assignment is left-associative, so it's equivalent to:

```
ArcChar = (ArcBit = 0);
```

The result of `ArcBit = 0` is the newly-assined value, that is - `0`, so it makes sense to assign that `0` to `ArcChar`

Answer (score 6):

It sets both variables to zero.

```
int i, j;
i = j = 0;
```

The same as writing

```
int i, j;
j = 0;
i = j;
```

or writing

```
int i, j;
i = 0;
j = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

An assignment operation (a = b) itself returns an rvalue, which can be further assigned to another lvalue; c = (a = b).  In the end, both a and c will have the value of b.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that it returned a value. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

That is just chaining of the assignment operator. The standard says in `6.5.16 Assignment operators`:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.
>   An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An
>   assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, but is not an
>   lvalue. The type of an assignment expression is the type of the left operand unless the
>   left operand has qualified type, in which case it is the unqualified version of the type of
>   the left operand. The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand shall
>   occur between the previous and the next sequence point.

So you may do something like:

```
a=b=2; // ok
```

But not this:

```
a=2=b; // error
```

Answer (score 3):

It assigns `ArcBit` to `0`, then assigns `ArcChar` to the value of the expression `ArcBit = 0`  (ie. `0`)

Answer (score 3):

In some languages, assignments are *statements*: they cause some action to take place, but they don't have a value themselves. For example, in Python<sup>1</sup> it's forbidden to write

```
x = (y = 10) + 5
```

because the assignment `y = 10` can't be used where a value is expected.

However, C is one of many languages where assignments are *expressions*: they produce a value, as well as any other effects they might have. Their value is the value that is being assigned. The above line of code would be legal in C.

The use of two equals signs on one line is interpreted like this:

```
ArcChar = (ArcBit = 0);
```

That is: `ArcChar` is beging assigned the value of `ArcBit = 0`, which is `0`, so both variables end up being `0`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *`x = y = 0` is actually legal in Python, but it's considered a special-case of the assignment statement, and trying to do anything more complicated with assignments will fail.*

Answer (score 2):

Assignment in C is an expression, not statement. Also you can freely assign values of different size (unsigned char to int and vice versa). Welcome to C programming language :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables

Moreover,

`[a int] = 0;` is possible.

`[a char] = 0;` is possible too.

arcbit and arcchar equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

As Hasturkun said, this is due to operator associativity order
[C Operator Precedence and Associativity](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The equal sign is an operator which assigns a value to a variable, and returns the value that the variable was assigned to. This means

```
x = 2;
```

returns `2`. We can exploit this to set two variables to one value in one line. So the following 3 statements are the same.

```
x = y = 2;
x = (y = 2);
y = 2; x = y;
```

The following, very common, statement works for the same reason.

```
FILE *f;
if ((f = fopen("cheese.txt"), "r") == EOF) { exit(1) }
fclose(f);
```