# Setting Two Variables on One Line

Tags: c#

I inherited an application with the following code and am deciding how to improve it. It seems to me that the second line of code is completely useless since the cpUserId is just going to get set with the value for strPartnerNo. So, can I just remove the second line of code completely?

```
strPartnerNo = meg.GetValue("MESSAGE_V1").ToString();

cpUserId = getFunction.GetValue("E_CONTACT").ToString();

leadUser.UserBP = cpUserId = strPartnerNo;
```

The following SO post seems to suggest I can completely remove the second line of code. [Two Equal Signs in One Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244114/two-equal-signs-in-one-line)

Comment: The stranger question is why is `cpUserId` being set to a value that is thrown away on the next line?  So unless `GetValue` has a necessary side-effect then yes it can be removed.

Comment: @DStanley I think the programmer that wrote the code did not know what they were doing.

Comment: Personally, I'd throw it all away.

Comment: It looks like you can remove that line, but a better way of answering these questions might be to write a test around that assertion and compare the refactored implementation to the output of the original version.

Comment: Before throwing it away just make sure you have a unit test that test the logic behind the treatment. The basic of refactoring.

Comment: it wouldn't hurt to make sure that `GetValue` doesn't have some radical side effects that you haven't noticed.  Sometimes people do things for a reason, even if they're just awful.

Comment: The second line looks like something that Resharper would flag up as "the assigned value is not used in any execution path."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**; your second line is not being used and can be deleted.

You are assigning cpUserId the same value as strPartnerNo in the last line.

Comment: Be careful though: Because you inherited the application you should make sure to check if the implementation of `GetValue` and possibly overriden `ToString` has any side effects before throwing it away.

Comment: Since the original code didn't seem to mind I made the assumption that it would be business-as-usual if that line was removed. Sometimes if things are inherited its a rabbit hole to determine why things were changed. Especially code that looks like it wasn't used in a while.

Answer (score 3):

```
leadUser.UserBP = cpUserId = strPartnerNo;
```

is equivalent to:

```
cpUserId = strPartnerNo;
leadUser.UserBP = cpUserId;
```

Therefore, you can omit the second line.

Answer (score 0):

`getFunction.GetValue()` function may do internal operations, but if only matters the final result of `cpUserId`, then YES, you can delete the second line.