# C Decision Control Explain

Tags: c

Why output is z=0 in the program written below ?
why isn't it giving any error?
Please Explain

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int x=3,y,z;
   y=x=10;
   z=x<10;
   printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d",x,y,z);
   return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
x=10, y=10, z=0
```

Comment: You assign `10` to `x`, and then you assign the result of `x<10` to `z`, what did you expect?

Comment: You meant to type  `y = x == 10`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244114/two-equal-signs-in-one-line

Answer (score 1):

According to [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft ([c11](/questions/tagged/c11)):

**6.5.9 Equality operators**

> The `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational operators except for their lower precedence. Each of the operators yields `1` if the specified relation is true and `0` if it is false. **The result has type** `int`.

So in your case, condition is false, because `10` is not less that `10`, so `0` is stored to the `z`.

Comment: It's curious that you quote the equality operators when the question uses a 'relational operator' `<`.  The net result is much the same — 0 is assigned if the operator evaluates to false and 1 if it evaluates to true — but …