# How can I assign two diffrent values to two variables at the same time

Tags: c#

I want to assign values to multiple variables at the same time. I know how it works in python but I need a equivalent for C#.

I found out that if I want to assign a value to a new variable I can do it like this.

```
int a = 1 , b = 1;
//This works fine but now I need to set the variables again
a = b , b = a + b;
//But i can't do it like that
//I know that in python it would look like this (a , b = b , a+b)
```

Comment: This looks like C# question. Why the python tag? I removed it.

Comment: It's just a matter of syntax, why would it be interesting for you to do so? I mean, after the compiling of a program and the generation of the machine code, they will be considered as two totally different lines of code whether they are in the same line or not!

Comment: @PhiloJunkie - Python's multiple assignment of `a, b = b, a+b` actually comes out with a different result from `a = b; b = a+b`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sorry I should've paid more attention before asking! You are right.

Comment: I guess you want this because that would be a body of some statement above (e.g. `if`). Otherwise requirement "one-liner" makes little sense as two lines barely expose any sort of problem to readability. In c# statement body can be also a *code block* (not sure in term): `{ b = a + b; a = b; }`. Note the order. Or you can simply use `a = b = a + b;` (for this there is a duplicate).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Equal Signs in One Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244114/two-equal-signs-in-one-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is valid C#, using tuples introduced in C# 7:

```
int (a, b) = (1, 2);
(a, b) = (b, a + b);
```

I wouldn't say this is idiomatic C# - I've never seen it in the wild, and I don't think many people know that you can do this - but it's valid.

The compiler doesn't actually use the ValueTuple class to do this - it synthesises the following code:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int temp1 = b;
int temp2 = a + b;
a = temp1;
b = temp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I got you right, but is this what you are looking for?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int a = 1, b = 1;
      a = b = (a + b);
      Console.WriteLine($"{a} {b}");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't do the right thing. The result should be "1 2" not "2 2".

Answer (score 0):

Would
    b += b;
work for you, as a == b?!

Comment: No, if i do it like this it is the same result as if i just count a = b and then count b = b + a